# How to ignore a pivot table while copying if it has no relevant filters

Tags: excel, vba

I Have created a PIVOT table with two combinations of filters...
Say Filter A is Yes and Filter B is Yes... I need to copy the data from pivot if and only if both are Yes else the pivot should be ignored in copying the data

Creation of Pivot table and selecting the filter as Yes is done through VBA code... Hence we don't know where the table has both filters Yes until the code execution got completed

```
'Create Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 1), _
TableName:="PivotTable1")

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable1 = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 1), TableName:="PivotTable1")


'Insert Row Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("CLIENT_PATIENT_ID")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With


With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("ED")
.Orientation = xlPageField
.Position = 1
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("ED"). _
EnableMultiplePageItems = True

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("ED")

.PivotItems("No").Visible = False

End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Diabetes")
.Orientation = xlPageField
.Position = 2
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Diabetes"). _
EnableMultiplePageItems = True
 End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Diabetes")

.PivotItems("No").Visible = False

'Copy data from PIVOT

Set PivotTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
PivotTable.DataBodyRange.Copy

'Paste the copied data from PIVOT
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PivotTable").Range

ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Calculate").Range("B2")

End With

End With
```

VBA code has to ignore if the filters are not Yes for both conditions

Comment: @PEH.. any solution for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to check for a pivot table filter.

> **NOTE**: there's a difference between applying an actual filter (`PivotFilter`) to a pivot table field (manually or via VBA), and setting the visibility of pivot fields (manually or via VBA). A pivot filter is a logical condition with a variety of pivot filter types (`XlPivotFilterType`). If any filters are set on a field, the `.PivotFields(<fieldname>).PivotFields.Count` will be greater than 0. Changing the visibility of items in a pivot field will may seem exactly the same, but since it's not a `PivotFilter`, the `.PivotFields.Count` will be 0.

For my example, I have data defined with a pivot table like this:

[image]

Then to check for a filter, you have to specify which field you're looking at and then the value of the specific filter. So if I define a filter like this:

[image]

Then to check for a filter, you have to specify which field you're looking at and then the value of the specific filter. So if I define a filter like this

then the filter in the pivot table will be set with these terms:

- Pivot field name = "Color"
- Pivot filter value 1 = "Red"
- Pivot filter value 2 = `vbNullString`  (essentially undefined/unused)
- Pivot filter type = `xlCaptionEquals` (see [XlPivotFilterType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpivotfiltertype))

I created a function to check these values in a given table:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim pTable As PivotTable
    Set pTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

    Debug.Print "The table is filtered: " & _
                PivotFilterExists(pTable, "Color", "Red", xlCaptionEquals)
End Sub

Public Function PivotFilterExists(ByRef pTable As PivotTable, _
                                  ByVal fieldName As String, _
                                  ByVal checkValue As Variant, _
                                  ByVal checkFilter As XlPivotFilterType) As Boolean
    PivotFilterExists = False

    Dim pField As PivotField
    Set pField = pTable.PivotFields(fieldName)

    Dim pFilters As PivotFilters
    Set pFilters = pField.PivotFilters

    '--- check if a filter is set to show only the requested value
    If pFilters.Count > 0 Then
        Dim pFilter As PivotFilter
        Set pFilter = pFilters.Item(1)
        If (pFilter.Value1 = checkValue) And _
           (pFilter.filterType = checkFilter) Then
            PivotFilterExists = True
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Just to be complete, "filtering" the pivot table using the checkmarks is done by disabling the visibility of items in the field. This condition will require looping through the field items and checking each one for visibility -- which can get complicated if you are allowing more than one item to be shown.

[image]

Comment: Hi PeterT
Thanks for the inputs and explanation...
But how it will resolve ignoring the pivot table which i dint want?

Comment: You can modify the example above to check for as many filter conditions as you wish and then use logic to determine what combinations to accept or ignore. For example, if you use a variable `Dim redFilter As Boolean`, then you `redFilter = PivotFilterExists(pTable, "Color", "Red", xlCaptionEquals)`. Check for a different filter by using `Dim blueFilter As Boolean; blueFilter = PivotFilterExists(pTable, "Color", "Blue", xlCaptionEquals)`. Just combine these in a If statement to check, such as `If redFilter And blueFilter Then ...` or `If redFilter And Not blueFilter Then...`. Whatever you want.